# How do I convert XML image data in HEX to Image that can be viewed with Livecode

Tags: livecode

I am trying to convert an image presented as HEX data (comes in as HEX in a XML file) back into an image that I can display using my stack user interface. I have tried every option that I could think of and could find in forums and manuals and ended up with the binaryEncode function:   binaryEncode(formatsList,dataStringList) and tried all possible "formatsList" options (e.g. h,H,C,etc.). One example in my stack:

```
on mouseUp
  put field "Field2" into tHex
  put binaryEncode("x*",tHex) into URL "binfile:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VV/test.png"
end mouseUp
```

The HEX data is comma separated as per the dictionary and is something like: FF,D8,FF,E0,00,11,4A,46,49,46,00,01,01,01,00,00,00 etc. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little slow, but it is pretty much guaranteed to work:

```
repeat for each item myHex in fld "Field2"
  put numToChar("0x" & myHex) after myBinary
end repeat
put myBinary into url "binfile:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VV/test.png"
```

It converts every hex word into its binary equivalent. If you'd add the line `put myBinary` to the end, you should recognize the PNG format (if the original image is in PNG format).

On a side note, it is a little dangerous to call a field "Field2". You might easily make a mistake and write "Field 2", which would be a completely different field with number 2 instead of the field with name "Field 2". I'd recommend using slightly more inventive names.

Comment: Thanks Mark - you are a star !! Yup - that field naming was merely used as quick example.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here's what you were originally aiming for;

```
put field "Field2" into tHex
replace comma with empty in tHex
put binaryEncode("H*", tHex) into  URL "binfile:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VV/test.png"
```

Comment: He wrote he already tried this. That's why I offered a different approach.

Comment: Yes, I can read  :)   He was on the right track with the correct function, but just didn't get it working.  The example above works and is far more efficient.